# Background job manager for Java?

Tags: java, maven

In the .NET world when you need to implement an app which will do processing in the background there are various libraries like [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/) for example.
But I am not able to find an equivalent in Java? What will be a good library for managing background tasks in Java?

Comment: You can have some Daemon Threads to do background jobs. When the main thread stops Daemon Threads will die. May be it suits your needs. Have a look at Worker and Executors in java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand completely the scope of Hangfire, but it sounds like the same kind of tasks I have solved using [Quartz Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/)

Answer (score 4):

The metioned Quartz Scheduler works very well. Also supports clustering using a database.

If you need to dig deep into batch processing there is [Spring-Batch](http://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/). It comes along with quite some good practices regarding transactions, skip or retry mechanisms. There is also a [Spring-Batch-Admin interface](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch-admin/screenshots.html).